# Account Settings Action required

Tags: google-analytics

I don't think this has anything to do with gtag.js because it's the same for all my properties. I think it has something to do with my account itself. But I can't tell what action is required.

[image]

Here's what the code looks like:

```
<ga-action-required ng-if="ctrl.isActionRequired" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
<div class="admin-action-required">
    <md-chips class="ng-isolate-scope md-ga-theme" tabindex="-1">
        <md-chips-wrap id="_md-chips-wrapper-320" tabindex="-1" 
            ng-keydown="$mdChipsCtrl.chipKeydown($event)" 
            ng-class="{ 'md-focused': $mdChipsCtrl.hasFocus(),                       
            'md-readonly': !$mdChipsCtrl.ngModelCtrl || $mdChipsCtrl.readonly,                      'md-removable': $mdChipsCtrl.isRemovable() }" class="md-chips md-readonly" aria-label="Chips input." role="list">
            <md-chip class="ng-scope md-ga-theme" role="listitem" aria-setsize="1">
                <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons-extended" aria-hidden="true" 
                ng-bind="::'warning'" 
                class="ng-binding md-ga-theme material-icons-extended" role="img">
                warning
                </md-icon>
                <div class="text-container"> Action required </div>
            </md-chip>
            <!-- ngRepeat: $chip in $mdChipsCtrl.items --> 
            <!-- ngIf: !$mdChipsCtrl.readonly && $mdChipsCtrl.ngModelCtrl --> 
            </md-chips-wrap>
    </md-chips>
</div>
```

Comment: If you click it or hover over it, doesn't it tell you?

Comment: On hovering over "Action required", the cursor changes, but clicking it doesn't do anything. The cursor is an I-beam when hovering over Account Settings.

Comment: Have you checked your email? Sometimes google will email when action is to be taken.

Comment: The notifications bell says that my property is not receiving any hits, but real time shows 1 user (me).